# how to use a while loop correctly

Tags: java

Write a program that uses a while loop to perform the following steps:
Comment by labelling each part: //Part A, //Part B, etc...
A.)Prompt the user to input 2 integers: firstNum and secondNum. Use 10 and 20.
B.)Output all odd numbers between firstNum and secondNum.
C.)Output the sum of all even numbers between firstNum and secondNum.
D.)Output the numbers and their square between 1 and 10.
E.)Output the sum of the square of odd numbers between firstNum and secondNum.
F.)Output all uppercase letters.

Again I am new to while loops and I am totally lost. I have tried reading a bunch but I am better at learning if someone shows me how to do something. I am open to all suggestions. I have just completed 8 other programs using if else statements and now trying to get the hang of loops. Thanks!

This is my pathetic attempt so far LOL

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class whileLoop
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Part A
        int firstNum = 10;
        int secondNum = 20;

        System.out.println("Please enter two integers: ");
        int oddNum = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Part B
        while(firstNum <= secondNum)
                {
                 if(firstNum % 2 != 0)
                 }
              oddNum = firstNum + secondNum;
              firstNum++;
                 }
                 System.out.println(""+oddNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: half-troll, half-sprawl . i'm taken aback by this

Comment: It's really very simple.  There is a "condition" in the `while` statement.  This condition can be true or false.  When one comes to the `while` statement the condition is evaluated, and if it's TRUE then the "body" (statements between `{}`) of the `while` statement is executed.  When the "body" completes (gets to the bottom, just before the `}`), we jump back to the top and test the condition again.  If the condition is ever FALSE we jump to the next statement after the closing `}` of the `while` "body".

Comment: `{ if(firstNum % 2 != 0) }` doesn't make any sense. You don't have a statement specifying what to do if the condition is true. Perhaps you meant `if(firstNum % 2 != 0) {oddNum = firstNum + secondNum; firstNum++;}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to do this:

```
 //Part B
 int temp = firstNum;
 while(temp <= secondNum)
 {
    if(temp % 2 != 0)
    {
       System.out.println(""+temp);
    }
    temp++;
 }
```

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for! I couldnt figure out how to write it correctly. Do I use this for the the rest of the steps as well? and how would i properly initialize firstNum and secondNum?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to show you how to use while loop on

Output all odd numbers between firstNum and secondNum.
Output the sum of all even numbers between firstNum and secondNum. 
Output the sum of the square of odd numbers between firstNum and secondNum.

```
int i=firstnumber;    
int sum=0;
int sumofsqr=0;
while(i<=secondnumber){
      if(i%2==0){
           System.out.println(i);
           sum+=i;
      }
      else{
           sumofsqr+=i*i;
      }
      i++;
}
System.out.println("Sum of odd " + sum + " Sum of sqr of even " + sumofsqr);
```

Comment: Okay thanks! although i thnk you mixed it up. I need the sum of all even numbers and the sume of the square of odd numbers.

Comment: Also, how am i supposed to piece this all together to look neat and flow? Mine is all chopped up and doesnt compile lol. Im missing things and just basically piecing it together off what you had givin me

Comment: It is just example to show u while loop, further u must go by youself